# How was paint supplied while painting the Sistine Chapel?

Tags: art, painting

Paint today is expensive (for quality supplies, anyway), and I expect that the paint used in the Sistine Chapel was quite good quality, due to its endurance.  There was also a *lot* of paint used there.  When Michelangelo ran out of paint, who supplied and paid for it (or the supplies required to make it), and how was it supplied?  What did he do when he needed more?

EDIT: clarified that I'm interested in the economics and supply chain.

Comment: Pre-mixed paint for use by artists first appeared in the 18th century. ([Primer on the history of paint](https://www.earthdate.org/colorful-history-of-paint).) Like other artists before that, Michelangelo made (or supervised the making of) his own paint.

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. Can you explain why the relevant Wikipedia pages and google searches didn't answer the question?  [SE sites work best if the questions are supported by preliminary research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2085030)

Comment: It wasn't just paint. [The Sistine Chapel was done in fresco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistine_Chapel_ceiling), which means painting on wet plaster, usually a few feet square at a time. The wet plaster was laid down at the beginning of the day and Michelangelo did his sketch directly on the plaster, followed by a wash of color, and then the details of that painted section. The durability of the painting is due to the interaction of the wet plaster and the paint, which "fused the colors into the wall"